# QGIS : how to get selected feature "state" to filter data in QGIS Composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer, filter

In a QGIS layer, I have selected some entities.

Is it possible to show these in a particular way using style definition using a "state" like $currentfeature or @atlas_featureid ?

[image]

The goal is to gather automatically only selected values in the composer map and attribute table and set composer map extents to the selection extent.

[image]

This would enable the user to simply select and print its data without caring much about printed map extent and printed attribute table synchronisation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you install Nathan Woodrow's "**Expression Plus**" plugin you're able to use a "isselected" function that can be useful to filter your table.

The syntax is the following :

**isselected**(layername), returning a boolean

Comment: Nice, thanks! We should have this in core on 3.X